# Section command with default spaces between title and rule

Tags: macros, sectioning, titlesec

Ho can I create a section command that provides the same spaces between the `\titlerule` and the title of the original `\section` command? The overall look must be equal to the original `\section` command. So, Is it better use the `\titlerule` command insted of the `\rule` command?

P.S. In the picture below I have forgotten a "to", sorry.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,cleardoublepage=empty,oneside,openany,final,10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\newcommand*{\Section}[1]{%
\textsc{#1}\newline%
\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}\newline%
\normalsize%
\normalfont%
\vspace*{.4\baselineskip}%
\large%
\textit{Curriculum Vit\ae}%
\normalsize\normalfont%
}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\raggedright}{}{0em}{\scshape}[\titlerule\normalsize\normalfont\vspace*{.4\baselineskip}\large\textit{Curriculum Vit\ae}\normalsize\normalfont]

\begin{document}

\section{Mario Rossi}

\vspace*{50pt}

\Section{Mario rossi}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The baseline of `rule` must be shifted. Therefor you can use the optional argument of `rule`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,cleardoublepage=empty,oneside,openany,final,10pt]{scrreprt}
\newcommand*{\Section}[1]{%
\noindent\textsc{#1}\newline%
\rule[0.5\ht\strutbox]{\textwidth}{.4pt}\newline%
\normalsize%
\normalfont%
\vspace*{.4\baselineskip}%
\large%
\textit{Curriculum Vit\ae}%
\normalsize\normalfont%
}
\begin{document}
\Section{Mario rossi}
\end{document}
```

By the way: I don't think that `scrbook` is really a good choice for a CV. I think `scrartcl` is more suitable.

Comment: I can see the difference in the spacing only by looking at it. How can I set the spacing at the same value of that provided from titlesec package in a automatic manner not only by looking at it? I have tryed to look into the scrbook.cls and the titlesec.sty files to find the correct spacing factor but I have not find it...

Comment: @FormlessCloud: Which space do you mean?

Comment: Please, look at the picture in my question. However I mean the space between "Mario Rossi" and the rule as well the space between the rule and "Curriculum Vitae"

Comment: @FormlessCloud: Do you mean `\titleformat{\section}{\large\raggedright}{}{0em}{\scshape}[\titlerule\vspace*{\dp\strutbox}\normalsize\normalfont\large\textit{Curriculum Vit\ae}\normalsize\normalfont]`

Comment: oh sorry, yeah the upper one in my picture is from the original section command, and the other below is from the custom section command like I have typed the commands in my MWE. However, yes I mean that I would to copy the spaces from the original section command, customized by the titlesec package with the \titleformat command

Answer (score 1):

One way to define your command would be like this:

```
\newcommand{\Section}[1]{\bigskip\noindent\bgroup\large\textsc{#1}\hfil\break
\vskip-8pt\hrule\vskip6pt\noindent\textit{Curriculum Vit\ae}\egroup\par}
```

and then adjust the two vskips as you want them, to get the right spacing around the rule.

Comment: The manual control via 8pt/6pt can be avoided by using `strut`. It much clearer and of course it uses the current font size.